# Язык C, UB при изменении const

Tags: c, const, неопределённое-поведение

1. Подскажите, действительно ли в **Стандарте** сказано, что *обходное* изменение `const` объекта - это неопределенное поведение? Я попытался найти эту информацию самостоятельно, но мне не удалось.
2. И если это действительно так (в чем я почти уверен), то я не совсем понимаю, в каких случаях применимо это правило.

   Например, даже в таком простом примере не все очевидно:

   ```
   const int a = 1;
   int *b = (int*)&a;// Это уже UB или еще нет?
   *b = 2;// Это точно UB?
   ```

   Относительно такого я не могу сделать каких-либо предположений:

   ```
   const int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
   int *b = (int*)a;// UB?
   *b = 1;// UB?
   ```

   Это тоже не ясно:

   ```
   int i = 1;
   const int *a = &i;
   // Может, на следующей строке компилятор посчитает, что объект,
   // на который указывает "a", является константным?
   int *b = (int*)a;
   *a = 2;// И эта операция приведет к UB?
   ```

   И это:

   ```
   // Абсолютно необходимая функция...
   void f(void *const _p)
   {
       void **p = (void**)&_p;
       *p = NULL;
   }
   ```
3. Часто встречал в код-гайдах компаний требования использовать `const` везде, где это только возможно. Например, имеется функция, которая помещает указатель на данные в связный список. Поскольку функция не собирается изменять данные или указатель на данные, а так же указатель на сам контейнер, то обычно функция выглядит так:

   ```
   int list_push_front(list *const _list,
                       const void *const _data)
   {
       // ...

       // И приходится делать так...
       new_node->data = (void*)_data;

       // ...
   }
   ```

   А ведь мы всего-лишь хотели сказать, что функция не меняет вставляемые в список данные, а так же не меняет входные параметры-указатели, *защищая* проект от некоторых видов *ниндзя-багов*.

   Так можно делать? Будет ли это действительно *хорошим тоном*, или последующее приведение `(void*)` является **UB**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Стандарт C11 6.7.3/6:

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

---

```
int *b = &a;// Это уже UB или еще нет?
```

Модификации пока еще нет, есть только присваивание несовместимых типов указателей. Это нарушение ограничений (constraint violation), но ещё не UB.

В стандарте есть похожий пример (6.5.16.1/6):

```
const char **cpp;
char *p;
const char c = 'A';
cpp = &p; //constraint violation
*cpp = &c; //valid
*p = 0; //valid
```

> The first assignment is unsafe because it would allow the following valid code to attempt to change the value of the const object c

Сказано, что присваивание небезопасно (unsafe), т.к. позволяет менять константное значение (о чем выше сказано, что это UB), но само преобразование не даёт UB.

Чуть более подробно:

```
cpp = &p; // сохраняем в cpp адрес указателя p
*cpp = &c; // записываем в p адрес константы c 
*p = 0; // попытка обнулить константу c (UB)
```

Если вывести после этого кода значения `*p` и `c`, можно увидеть, например, следующее:

- [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TFS9JvIRk2XN51dj): `0 0`
- [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/K4iwUkqnyAsSxLGI) `0 65`

Типичные результаты для неопределённого поведения. В первом случае константа обнулилась, во втором случае по сути одинаковые данные имеют разные значения.

---

```
const int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Выражение справа не является константым, т.е. не будь здесь левой части, память, выделенная `malloc` доступна для модификации, а значит косвенное её изменение не есть изменение константного объекта, т.е. допустимо. Это моё размышление, надо смотреть стандарт более подробно.

---

Преобразование из п.3 вашего вопроса по сути не отличается от ситуации в п.1. Мы просто преобразуем указатель для хранения. В дальнейшем, если исходные данные изменяемы (не объявлены как `const`), то по новому указателю эти данные можно менять, иначе получим UB.

Кстати, список всех UB приведён в разделе **J.2 Undefined behavior** стандарта.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, почему **cpp = &p;** является опасным.

Comment: По-поводу списка всех **UB** в конце стандарта - там представлен не совсем полный список, потому что в стандарте явно говорится о том, что **UB** может возникать и в ситуациях, не описанных в стандарте.

Comment: Мне кажется, что преобразование char* => const char*, а затем преобразование const char* => char* и последующее изменение объекта через указатель на неконстантный объект все же может являться **UB**. Это мы знаем, что изначальный объект не является константным, но ведь компилятор запросто может решить, что раз перед изменением объекта для целевого адреса/указателя произошло преобразование const char* => char*, значит объект константен.

Comment: @Максим расписал подробнее про опасное преобразование.

Comment: А, кажется понял. Я привык считать, что проблемы могут возникнуть лишь в том случае, если в указатель на неконстантные данные записывается адрес константных данных. А оно, оказывается, может привести к проблемам и в обратную сторону... И как же за всем этим следить? Во многих библиотеках, в том же **GTK**, **const** используется для *гарантий* и соблюдения правил хорошего тона... Но все это правильное дело, помноженное на обратные вызовы и сложное пробрасывание указателя, порождает трудно понимаемые цепочки преобразований, которые могут привести к **UB** в месте.

Comment: В примере из стандарта получается, что каждая из трех операций сама по себе валидна. Но их комбинация является невалидной. Хм, интересно.

Comment: @Максим в описанной ситуации имеется двойной указатель, поэтому "обратная сторона" и возможна. Такого чтобы UB ситуация не была описана в стандарте - быть не должно. Могут быть всякие расширения компилятора или просто не соответствие его стандарту, или баги в стандарте, но это совсем другая история. По опасному преобразованию выводится предупреждение, поэтому его можно всё же довольно легко обнаружить.

Comment: @Максим Насчёт комбинации: присваивание нуля переменной и деление на некоторую переменную отдельно являются валидными операциями. Но если поделить на 0, то тоже получим UB. Так что UB в "комбинациях" это обычный случай.

Comment: И есть ли какие-то разумные способы защиты от таких *совпадений*? Например, приведенная мной функция **list_push_front()** своей сигнатурой говорит о том, что она не меняет данные, которые вставляются в список. Но возможна и другая интерпретация такой сигнатуры. И что, если вызывающий передаст в функцию указатель на действительно константные данные? Например, указатель на строковой литерал. Как это отлавливать? И как в случае проблем понять, в какой части кодовой базы абсолютно корректные и выверенные сущности в сумме дали **UB**?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83429/discussion-between-alexolut-and-).